# Does anyone have a beginners guide to installing and using glassfish?

Tags: java, eclipse, glassfish

I am after a all round installation and introduction to Glassfish.

(ie Your boss has told you need to develop your web applications for glassfish instead of tomcat)

Comment: http://javadude.wordpress.com/2009/01/03/tutorial-starting-with-glassfish-and-jms/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Installing

Installing Glassfish onto your own PC for testing.

- Download the installer file off the glassfish website
- Move the installer jar to the location you wish the files to be installed. Once
  installed, the install folder can not be moved. If you are not sure where to place it on OS/X or Linux, drop the installer jar into `/usr/local/`, this will result in your appserver being installed as `/usr/local/glassfish`
- Run the installer with extra memory `java -Xmx256m -jar glassfish-installer-xxx.jar`
- Run the configuration script: `cd glassfish; lib/ant/bin/ant -f setup.xml`

### Starting the app server

To start glassfish with the default configuration type `bin/asadmin start-domain domain1`. This will result in the following URL's becoming available:

- Admin website http://localhost:4848/
- Application site [http://localhost:8080/](http://localhost:4848/)

The default administrator username and password are:

- **Username:** admin
- **Password:** adminadmin

### IDE support

#### Eclipse support

The easiest way to get Glassfish working under Eclipse 3.5 is to use this software Update url (https://ajax.dev.java.net/eclipse) inside Eclipse.

### Caveats and warnings

- For those used to storing application settings and configuration in a `context.xml` file, glassfish does not support this.

### Moving on from here

The following links are also very useful:

- [Guide to JMS in glassfish](http://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2008/01/22/jms-messaging-using-glassfish.html)
- [Guide to JMS in glassfish in Netbeans](http://javadude.wordpress.com/2009/01/03/tutorial-starting-with-glassfish-and-jms/)